# What structure to use for dynamic key sort and query?

Tags: java, sorting, dynamic

```
public class Book {
    private Long id;
    private Long quantity;
}
```

I want a map that sort the quantity of books, but the quantity always change, how to sort this when quantity changed, be carefully quantity could be same for different books.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use tow maps, one for storing all the books, another for sorting by quantity.

Here is the test codes:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Book {
    private Long id;
    private Long quantity;

    public Book(Long id, Long quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Long getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", quantity=" + quantity +
                '}';
    }
}

class Books {
    // id -> Book
    private final Map<Long, Book> books = new HashMap<>();
    // q -> idSet
    private final SortedMap<Long, Set<Long>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

    public void save(Book book) {
        Book old = books.get(book.getId());
        books.put(book.getId(), book);

        // q -> idSet
        Long q = book.getQuantity();
        Set<Long> idSet = sortedMap.get(q);
        if (null == idSet) {
            idSet = new HashSet<>();
        }
        idSet.add(book.getId());

        // sorted by quantity
        sortedMap.put(q, idSet);

        // remove id from old idSet
        if (old != null) {
            Long oq = old.getQuantity();
            if (!q.equals(oq)) {
                idSet = sortedMap.get(oq);
                idSet.remove(book.getId());
                if(idSet.isEmpty()){
                    sortedMap.remove(oq);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Book getBook(Long id) {
        return books.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("Books{\n");
        sortedMap.forEach((q, idSet) -> {
            b.append(String.format("%8d: ", q));
            idSet.forEach(id -> b.append(books.get(id)).append(' '));
            b.append('\n');
        });
        b.append('}');
        return b.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Books t = new Books();

        t.save(new Book(1L, 1L));
        t.save(new Book(2L, 2L));
        t.save(new Book(3L, 3L));
        t.save(new Book(4L, 1L));
        System.out.println(t);

        t.save(new Book(1L, 10L));
        System.out.println(t);

        t.save(new Book(2L, 20L));
        System.out.println(t);

        t.save(new Book(3L, 30L));
        System.out.println(t);

        t.save(new Book(5L, 50L));
        System.out.println(t);

        t.save(new Book(4L, 50L));
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 2 (usually) mutually exclusive operations here (identity and sorting), you will have to separate one from the other, as @Echo Ma suggested. However, I suggest that the sorting should be done when needed and not at insertion time.

Let us assume that you have a set or map, `bookSet`, where you have unique instances of `Book` by `id`, and that each instance is being updated with its quantity by some process. Then you can do the quantity-based sorting only when needed using a code something like below:

```
Comparator<Book> comparator = ( book1, book2 ) -> {
    long b1q = book1.getQuantity().longValue();
    long b2q = book2.getQuantity().longValue();

    if( b1q > b2q ) return 1;
    else if( b1q == b2q ) return 0;
    else return -1;
};

/* When you want the books list sorted by quantity, do this. (Assuming bookSet that has the list of unique Book instances with current quantities.) */
List<Book> sortedByQty = new ArrayList<>( bookSet );
Collections.sort( sortedByQty, comparator );
```